# Mapping Indirect Lookup field to Custom

Tags: trailhead, externalobjects

In the context of this Trailhead "Quick Start: Salesforce Connect": https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quickstart-lightning-connect, is created the OrderDB external data source and synced it. This validates step 1 and 2. On the 3rd step, i should change the field  Customer_ID__c field, in External Object "order", to a Standard Account object, and modify it to an Indirect Lookup.

But this object is unavailable, and the only ones i can map to are SmDocument and SmTag, and not Account

[image]

So what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

As in many other issues in Salesforce, the solutions was to restart the tutorial, that is to reinstall the package, and repeat the Set Customer IDs step.